# Simplifying $ f(x)=M_{ij}x_jx_i^*+M_{ij}^*x_j^*x_i $, for $x\in\Bbb{C}^n$ and $M\in\Bbb{C}^{n\times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$ and $M\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and is symmetric. We need to simplify the expression
> $$
> f(x)=M_{ij}x_jx_i^*+M_{ij}^*x_j^*x_i
> $$
> where $^*$ is the complex conjugate.

It is obvious that $f(x)$ is real, but I am stuck in the next to utilize the symmetric $M$,
$$
f(x)=\frac12(M_{ij}+M_{ij}^*)\Re{(x_jx_i^*)}?
$$

Comment: Define the complex scalar function $\mu=x^HMx,\;$
where $x^H=\left(x^*\right)^T$ is the hermitian conjugate. Then
$$f=(\mu^H+\mu)=x^H(M^H+M)x$$

Comment: Thanks to @greg. That is the point. I failed on the way to prove  $x_jx_i^*$ to be real.

Comment: The matrix $C_{ji}=x_jx_i^*$ is **not** _real_, in the usual sense of the term. The diagonal terms $C_{ii}$ are _real_, but the off-diagonal terms will be _complex_.

Comment: Yes, that is what I realized, but $C_{ji}+C_{ij}=x_jx_i^*+x_ix_j^*$ is real.